# In ejs, inside <% %> tag no html works

Tags: ejs

Can any one help for this issue: when i pass variables inside   tages as <%=%> for echo/print but no data print inside . But console.log shows the data that i want to show. If you've experienced regarding this issue please help, thanks in advance.

```
    <table class="table table-stripped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Last update time</th>
           <th>Key</th>
           <th>Value</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>

        webSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
        var received_msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
        var latestTelemetryData = received_msg.data;

        const keys = Object.keys(latestTelemetryData);
        //console.log('keys:', keys)
        //console.log('keys.length:', keys.length)
        if(keys.length > 0){
        keys.forEach((key, index) => {
        var telemetryValues = latestTelemetryData[key];
        %>                                
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= key %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=telemetryValues[0][0]%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=telemetryValues[0][1]%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% }); } else{ %>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="text-center">No data found</td>
            </tr>
            <% } }; %>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution of that problem. That's multi-lines of ejs code inside <% %> not parse as print. So it should be one line always for execute.
Example:

```
                      <tbody>
                        <% telemetryDataArr.forEach((key, index)=> { %>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <%= key.key %>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%= key.val %>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%= key.dt %>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <% }) %>
                       </tbody>
```